# When is firebase JS SDK v8 set to be deprecated

Tags: firebase

Since the launch of Firebase v9 is significantly different, I'm just wondering how much time there is to migrate our codebases before v8 is no longer supported.

Comment: Since this is not a programming question, and more directed at product managers at Firebase, it should be asked on a discussion forum, such as [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/) or [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no deprecation schedule for older Firebase SDKs. Most older SDKs continue work today, with many as far back as 2012.

That said, we hope that you'll upgrade to the v9 SDK because of the value it offers: a significantly reduced bundle size. To get started on v9 quickly, consider [using the `compat` paths](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat) which are drop-in compatible with v8.